# How to navigate between two html files in a Expressjs project

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

am relatively new to expressjs and for the life of me i can not figure out how to navigate between two HTML files in the root folder. Am using bootstrap anjularjs and expressjs for my project.

I have currently used the following code in the routes directory:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('profile', {title: ''});
});


module.exports = router;
```

In addition to this i have also made use of this statement in the app.js file to try and help with navigation:

```
app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')))
app.use('/html', express.static("html"));

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/profile', function (req,res){
    res.render('profile', {
        title: 'Profile'
    });
});
```

So my problem is this current error, any assistance with this would be appreciated:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\views"
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:579:17)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:960:7)
   at C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\app.js:52:7
   at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
   at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:310:13)
   at C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\app.js:41:2
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Brian Manda\Documents\fmg_code\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Your index is `.html`?

Comment: Yes, my index file is an html file

Answer (score 0):

Returns the rendered HTML of a view via the `callback` function. It accepts an optional parameter that is an object containing local variables for the view. It is like `res.render()`, except it cannot send the rendered view to the client on its own.
If you dont set the "ejs", automatically the app get the `.html` file, because res.render is for that.
In the case, my `html` file have name: `index` inside `public` folder.

If your `index` is `.html`:

```
var app = express();    

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render("../public/index"); //the archive html file
        });
```

If you `index` is '`.ejs`':

```
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set the index.ejs file

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render("../public/index.ejs"); // if you want, remove the .ejs, is optional, 
        });
```

Reference [here](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#app.render).